# How to express a double integral in terms of single integral in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to compute `int[0,10]int[0,y] f(x,y) dxdy` in matlab. Of course, I can use integral2 or quad2d to do it: `integral2(f,0,10,0,@(x)x)`. However, I can also treat `g(y)=nt[0,y] f(x,y) dx` and do the integral `int[0,10] g(y) dy`. Instead of using integral2, I want to use integral only to do the computation. The code I write is:

`g=@(y)integral(@(x)f(x,y),0,y)`

`integral(g,0,10)`

However, it gives error message that

`Error using integral (line 85)
A and B must be floating point scalars.`

My question is: is it possible to express double integral in terms of single integral? How to do it? Furthermore, I want to vectorize the integrals so that I can input for changing the number 10 to a vector, say 0:1:10?

Comment: Can you provide the code that you actually ran?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a small remark: symbolic integration and analytical solving is not the core of Matlab. Although it is limited supported, if you want to work analytical, there are better solutions, for example Mupad, an analytical environment inside Matlab.

That being said, what you are trying to do with `integrate` is a numerical integration. However a numerical integration is very hard if there are unknown boundaries. A better approach is to use a symbolic integration with the method `int`.

To answer your second question: I am afraid that vectorisation with symbolic integration is not possible.

I reworked your code to the following:

```
syms x
f = @(x,y) x+y
g = @(y) int(f(x,y), x, 0, y)
h = int(g(y), y, 0, 10)
```

The corresponding Matlab documentation: [int](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html?searchHighlight=int) and [integral](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html?searchHighlight=integral)